# unwated symbol in currency angularjs with Hybrid appp

Tags: angularjs, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on hybrid app. I have my code working in web but showing some unwanted symbol in hybrid app

```
Â

<span class="value-amount">{{topupMaximumAmt | currency:''}}</span>
```

output `Â20.00`

Comment: Your page is encoded in utf-8?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use the filter service:

```
ctrl.getCurrency = function (amount) { return $filter('currency')(amount, ""); };
```

Import the $filter service in you controller and call the above method from your template.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.

added

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8;">
```

in index.html

Comment: I mean, this is what i answered in the comment?